# PostgreSQL not starting in time

Tags: postgresql, recovery, wal

I have restored a backup from psql server A to psql server B.  When the postgresql service starts on server B, the log below is produced.  From what I read the invalid record length message is not a problem, just an indicator that the end of the last WAL file was reached.

However, when I attempt to run 'psql' it gives a fatal error that the database is starting up.  (I waited over an hour and still in that state).  I still can't run psql.  Note that standby.signal file is present on B, in case that matters.

What does this mean, and how do I fix it? Or is this normal while the standby.signal file is present?

```
2022-10-18 16:50:47.953 EDT [126144] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.5 (Debian 13.5-0+deb11u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-10-18 16:50:47.954 EDT [126144] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2022-10-18 16:50:47.954 EDT [126144] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2022-10-18 16:50:47.955 EDT [126144] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-10-18 16:50:47.963 EDT [126145] LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2022-10-18 16:50:47 EDT
2022-10-18 16:50:48.052 EDT [126145] LOG:  entering standby mode
2022-10-18 16:50:48.142 EDT [126145] LOG:  redo starts at 0/70000028
2022-10-18 16:50:48.142 EDT [126145] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/700000D8: wanted 24, got 0
pg_ctl: server did not start in time
2022-10-18 16:52:16.600 EDT [126876] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

Comment: Do you agree that you "specified neither primary_conninfo nor restore_command"?  If so, why do you think you don't need to?

Comment: How exactly did you restore the backup? Do you intend this server to be a standby, or a normal Postgres instance?

Comment: @jjanes - That was a typo in conf file, now fixed and questions updated with new log.  Thanks.  Problem still remains...

Comment: @mustaccio - I restored a tar of server A's directory (with postgresql service shutdown on both service during tar creation and extraction).  Server B is supposed to remain as a standby.  Does that mean it will stay in 'starting' mode until promoted to active?

Comment: If you look at the log, it says "entering standby mode". That means that you have a file `standby.signal` in your data directory. That seems wrong, if you are trying to restore a backup. The question cannot be answered, because you don't tell us what exactly you did and how you configured the server.

Comment: I have intentionally created the standby.signal file - I want server B to remain in standby mode.  Does being in standby mode mean that "the database system is starting" is normal?  (What's what in standby mode means)